# Assigning a different layout to wireless keyboard

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've recently replaced my external USB keyboard with a wireless one (for using laptop like desktop with external mouse and monitor as well, where external keyboard layout is different from the laptop keyboard layout).

With USB keyboard I had a not-so-perfect solution with a udev rule like this:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<VendorCode>", ATTRS{idProduct}=="<ProductCode>", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{XKBMODEL}="pc105", ENV{XKBLAYOUT}="<LayoutCode>", ENV{XKBVARIANT}="<VariantCodeIfAny>", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}=""
```

I wonder if a similar solution exists for wireless keyboard which will be effective before logging in to a desktop environment session (where it's of course easy to do this).

Comment: Here's a random link found on Internet that might help for the X11 case: https://lord.re/en/posts/70-multi-keyboard-layout/

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the tip, which helped me get the correct layout+variant by adding a second section in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` below a generic one automatically created by the system for my laptop keyboard. Now I only have a minor problem with it as this leads to a global change in KDE Plasma 5. It seems I need a better configuration (instead of the first or as a third section?) for my laptop keyboard. I'm now trying to find the right match criteria as I get very few items (e.g. no vendor, no model info) following the same instructions.